# BigQuery does not allow adding columns after dropping

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created BQ table with two columns:
col1 string nullable
col2 string required

And next populated table with some dummy data:

```
insert into `test.test` values ('val1', 'val2')
insert into `test.test` values (null, 'val2')
insert into `test.test` values ('val1', 'val2')
```

After that I dropped single column:

```
Alter table `test.test` drop column col2
```

And after that I would like to add new column:

```
alter table `test.test` add column col3 string
```

HINT: New column that I am trying to add is named differently than the one I deleted.
BQ raises an error to me:

```
Column `col2` was recently deleted in the table `test`. Deleted column name is reserved for up to the time travel duration, use a different column name instead.
```

It seems to be not right. I know that deleted columns is still kept somewhere in BQ world, but I am trying to add column with different name than the deleted one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/242214893) and is being worked upon by Bigquery Engineering team. You may click on **+1** to bring more attention on the issue and **STAR** the issue so that you can be notified for updates.

Meanwhile, as a workaround you try adding new field via

1. [BigQuery UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#add_a_column)
2. bq [command line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#bq)
3. API or Client Library